# IronPython returning duplicate values in C# callback function

Tags: c#, python, .net, callback, ironpython

In a file called `test.py` I have the following code:

```python
def foo(callback):
    callback(1, 2, 3)

def bar(x, y, z):
    print x, y, z
```

When `foo(bar)` is executed in the IronPython console, it outputs:

```python
1 2 3
```

I want to call `foo()` from a C# application. The following C# code executes `foo()`, passing it a C# callback function.

```C#
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile("test.py", scope);
scope.callbackFunction = new Action<int, int, int>
    ((x, y, z) => Debug.Print("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", x,y,z));
scope.foo(scope.callbackFunction);
```

The output is:

```C#
1   2   1
```

I can't figure out why `x == z`. Why is the C# output `1 2 1` instead of `1 2 3`? Am I sending it a C# callback function incorrectly?

I am running this on Windows 7, the C# application is targeted for .NET 4.5 and my IronPython version is 2.7.4.

Comment: Outside of a typo I can't think of a reason for this to happen. Is that the exact code you're using?

Comment: I have tried it with 4.5.1 and IronPython 2.7.5b2 and I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue anymore either. I recompiled and ran the program about 10 times without changing any code. The first six times I encountered this error. The last four times (and ever since then) this issue no longer occurs.

I assume there is a much deeper bug at play, but I doubt I will ever find out what it is.